# I want to return ids from model($data) to controller

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, ajax, codeigniter

[image]

In above image I select 3 record to insert I want to get these 3 records id from model to controller I want to access those in ajax success for print page

Controller:

```
public function createPaymentAllocation(){    

    $bilty_ids         = $this->input->post('due_ids');
    $biltyCount        = count($bilty_ids);

     $agent          = $this->input->post('agent');
     $due_to         = $this->input->post('due_to');

      for($i = 0; $i < $biltyCount; $i++){

      $data = array(
            'agent_id'            =>$agent,
            'pay_dueto'           =>$due_to,
            'mr_no'               =>$bilty_ids[$i],
             );

      $modelResult = $this->PayRecAllModel->inserPaymentAllocation($data);
      $this->PayRecAllModel->changeStatus($bilty_ids[$i]);
    }

      if(!empty($modelResult)){
         $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
                'form_status'     => 'true',
                'form_message'    => 'Payment Recovery  has been successfully Allocate'
                );

      }else{
            $data['PaymentRecAllocation'] = array(
                'form_status'     => 'false',
                'form_message'    => 'Something went wrong.'
            );
      }
      echo json_encode($data);
  }
```

Model:

```
public function inserPaymentAllocation($data){
                 print_r($this->input->post());
                 exit();

                if($this->db->insert('payment_rec_allocn', $data)){       

                        return   true;

                 }else {
                        return  false;
                 }
          }
```

after `print_r` in model it return following array.

```
Array
(
    [agent] => 291
    [rec_type] => lr_no
    [due_ids] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => 8
            [2] => 9
        )

)
```

How can I `return these 3 ids` after data insert to controller.

Comment: you can return as  `return $this->input->post('due_ids');` from model

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I get that ids but I want give in variable  ajax success data

Answer (score 0):

addd array in your code

```
$modelResult[] = $this->PayRecAllModel->inserPaymentAllocation($data);
```

Comment: You should explain a little more your answer. Just from this, it's really hard to tell how or why your answer works.

Comment: Insert ids will store in array, can you please make the answer is correct it will help others